# How to adjust max height to percentage while maintaining tbody only scroll?

Tags: html, css, header

I am using this method to scroll within tbody:

```
tbody {
      display:block;
      max-height:575px;
      overflow-y:scroll;
      }
thead, tbody tr {
      display:table;
      width:100%;
      table-layout:fixed;
      }
```

The issue I'm having is that using a fixed height in my instance makes inconsistencies across devices and I don't have the time to rewrite this for each potential device.  Ideally, what I'd like to do is fill 100% of the parent while maintaining tbody only scroll.  Is this possible?

I have read many posts about locking headers and have tried a number of the main ones, but none have worked exactly as I need it to.  The sample above is the closest I've come, but max-height doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using [CSS Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Assuming you have a HTML layout like this:

```
<table>
  <thead></thead>

  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

The following CSS will create a fixed header and scrollable body. The body will always fill the rest of the remaining space on the page.

```
table {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

tbody {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: So this works almost how I want it to, except that it extends past the bottom of the screen.  I have a header div, and it appears to extend about that size below the bottom of the screen.  I am going to play around with it to see if I can make it work.  Until then, any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Yes you can use the CSS calc function to compensate for the height of the header. If your header is 60px in height, then you can use `height: calc(100vh - 60px)`. If you're using SASS then it's a good idea to store that 60px in a variable that you use to give the header a fixed height, so if it ever changes then your table layout will be automatically updated too.